# postgresql select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create temp table tmp_apps (
  id integer
);

create temp table tmp_pos (
     tmp_apps_id integer,
     position integer
);

insert into tmp_apps
select 1 id union
select 2 id 
;

insert into tmp_pos (tmp_apps_id, position)
select 1 tmp_apps_id, 1 as position union all
select 1 tmp_apps_id, 1 as position union all
select 1 tmp_apps_id, 2 as position union all
select 1 tmp_apps_id, 3 as position union all
select 1 tmp_apps_id, 3 as position union all
select 2 tmp_apps_id, 1 as position
;
/*
Expected result:
tmp_apps_id tmp_pos_position
1           1,2
2           1
*/
```

How to get first 2 comma separated, distinct `tmp_pos.position` for each `tmp_apps.id` 
It is possible ?

Comment: +1 for a working test case. *That's* how you make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT tmp_apps_id
         , position
         , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp_apps_id ORDER BY position) AS rn
    FROM   tmp_pos
    GROUP  BY 1, 2
    ORDER  BY 1, 2
    )
SELECT tmp_apps_id, string_agg(position::text, ', ')
FROM   x
WHERE  rn < 3
GROUP  BY 1;
```

This happens to be much like the solution @araqnid posted a bit faster than me.
[CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) or subquery, that's just two ways for doing the same in this case.

My version is different in one important aspect:
By using **`GROUP BY`** instead of **`DISTINCT`** to get distinct values, you can apply the [window function **`row_number()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) (key element for the solution) in the same query level and do not need another subquery (or CTE).

The reason for this is that aggregation (`GROUP BY`) is applied **before** window functions while `DISTINCT` is applied **after**. In many situations `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` offer equally good solutions. In a case like this you can put the subtle difference to good use if you know it. I expect this to be quite a bit faster.

Comment: First I would like to thank you for the excellent answer.
I really surprised by grouping by column number and i want to ask:
In general case, this way gives speed increase in comparison with grouping by column name ?

Comment: @cetver: If you mean the ordinal numbers in [`GROUP BY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) and `ORDER BY`, then no. That's just notational convenience. No effect on performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
select tmp_apps_id, string_agg(position::text,',')
from (
 select tmp_apps_id, position,
        row_number() over (partition by tmp_apps_id order by position)
 from (
  select distinct tmp_apps_id, tmp_pos.position from tmp_pos
 ) x
) x
where row_number <= 2
group by tmp_apps_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) or `string_agg`, depending on your version of Postgres:

```
SELECT tmp_apps_id, array_agg(tmp_pos_position)
FROM tmp_pos_position
GROUP BY tmp_apps_id
```

In 9.0, use the `string_agg` function:

```
SELECT tmp_apps_id, string_agg(tmp_pos_position, ',')
FROM tmp_pos_position
GROUP BY tmp_apps_id
```

Comment: `string_agg` processes all records, but i need only 2 with distinct values